# MapsEngine Deprecated - can I call a layer in the same way from CartoDB?

Tags: carto, google-maps-engine

We have an online map that is built partly by calling a Google MapsEngine layer (http://dea.snowball.co.za/).  MapsEngine has been deprecated and we need to bring in this layer from somewhere else.

MapsEngine made it very easy by providing layerkeys etc.

```js
mapsEngineLayer[0] = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
            mapId: '08041245187153135450-08879288594674088841',
            layerKey: 'layer_00006',
            map: map,
            name: 'Reserves'
```

Can I do something similar from CartoDB?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about CartoDB but if you can get access to the layer from your data source in GeoJSON format, then you can use the [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) in the Maps API.